# How do you control the size of an mdc-form-field in material-components-web?

Tags: web, material-components

The title says it all really.  How do I control the width of a text field inside a form element with mdc?
I've also noticed that the form isn't centred by default but aligns to the left of the containing mdc-layout-grid__inner.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="mdc-layout-grid">
  <form>
    <div class="mdc-layout-grid__inner">
      <div class="mdc-textfield mdc-layout-grid__cell medc-layout-grid--span-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Is the best I've come up with.  The text fields take the size of the cell.  But the form isn't centre aligned.  I think that's a problem with the form element perhaps?